# Como mostrar tela de “carregando”

Tags: front-end, angular, componentes

Boa tarde, sou iniciante no angular e estou com a seguinte duvida:

É possível eu ter um seletor acessível em todos os meus componentes?

Trago meu componente da seguinte forma:

```
import { CarregandoComponent } from '../carregando/carregando.component';
@Component({
selector: 'app-questions',
templateUrl: './questions.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./questions.component.css'],
entryComponents: [CarregandoComponent]
})
```

O problema é que em todo html que eu queira o carregando devo colocar o seletor

```
<carregando[isRunning]="isRequesting"></carregando>
```

Gostaria de coloca-lo apenas em um lugar, tentei no index.html mas não teve efeito.

Alguém sabe me ajudar?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tu deve criar um serviço e.g `CarregandoComponentService` e carregá-lo no seu `app.module`. Assim ele se tornará um singleton em sua aplicação e qualqur subcomponente terá acesso à mesma instância deste serviço.

Depois, basta carregar o componente `CarregandoComponent` no html do seu `app.component.html` e utilizar `CarregandoComponentService` para fazer o controle deste através dos demais componentes.

Carregue o serviço no componente que quer usá-lo e você terá o controle do `CarregandoComponent`.